# Bitstring counting with three elements

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinatorics-on-words, bit-strings

A bitstring (length $10$ $\{0,1\}$) has exactly $120$ string that contains three $0$s, but now I am trying to find out how many strings with three zeroes if the string looks like this: $\{0,1,\phi\}$.

Can I still use binomial to figure it out?

Comment: Not following.  Are you saying that your string has length ten, starts $01$ and that the rest of the string has exactly two $0's$?  If so, then there are $\binom 82$ ways to place the two $0's$ and that placement determines the string.  Or are you asking something completely different?

Comment: Choose the locations of the zeroes.  There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to do this.  Then, for the remaining $7$ positions choose whether it was a $1$ or a $\varphi$, two choices each seven times for a total of $2^7$ ways to do this step.  Apply rule of product and conclude that there are $\binom{10}{3}\cdot 2^7$ such ternary strings of length ten with exactly three zeroes

Comment: The bitstring is only an example. I have a string with 3 elements {0,1,φ} and I am trying to figure out how I can calculate a string that containts exactly three zeros :)